# What are the steps for modifying an existing rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I am working on a web application written by ruby on rails. It has more than 10 models and I need to add some new attributes to some of the models as well as new methods and views. I also will need to remove or enhance some of the functionality. I know that I would need to generate new migrations and from there add/remove new columns. Then in controllers, add/modify methods, and update the views.

I wanted to know what would be the best steps (and in which order) for doing the above tasks. Also, do I need to change other files in folders like test or any other folder? What things should I consider to minimize the troubles later?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Best to first learn rails; start at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Once you are aware of how the framework works, the individual tasks become simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I have read that guide as well as some other tutorials. But because I am starting to modify a big project, I decided to ask this question to get some ideas about where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are new to rails, the first thing you should do is to read through [the getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). This will help you understand the fundamentals of the rails framework and the application you inherited. After that, there are several other guides worth reading (from the same site) that may be directly applicable to the work you are doing.

Another incredibly helpful resource is [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/). Some of these are outdated, but they are still a great starting place and can help introduce you to both new, powerful gems and rails techniques to get the work done faster and better.

As to your specific question, rails is built on an MVC architecture (meaning Model Views Controllers). It is in your best interest to try and follow this practice whenever possible. Reading up on this will clarify some of your questions as well.

When you run a migration, you will be modifying your database. The changes are viewable in the database schema (which should **never** be modified by hand, always modify it through migrations). This will add attributes to your models whose table you modified. In the controllers, you will add logic to deal with all of these things and the views will present the data to your users (or allow users to enter data). Asking which order is best is probably rather opinion based, but I would say you should modify the tables (run needed migrations) first. This way you can then generate the logic to deal with the new attributes. I would then create the controller logic and finally the views.

You also ask what other files need to be changed. This is heavily dependent on your system. At a base level, you should definitely be writing tests to support the logic you are generating (and many developers will advocate that you should do this *before* you write the other logic, a process called [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)).

TL;DR: Read the guides, work through a basic tutorial, and watch some Railscasts. This should get you up to speed on the process and best practices that go along with rails development.

Comment: Thanks for your addressing all parts of my question. Actually I have read some guides and worked on some tutorials. But because they usually talk about starting from scratch, I wanted to make know if there are other special considerations that I need to take into account when modifying an existing project. For example I have read that to have security it is good to update the ruby and gems' versions. But because my existing project uses old ruby version and has a lot of gems, I am afraid that if I try to use newer versions of ruby and rails, I might get a lot of errors or misfunctionality.

Comment: That's going to be a different issue all together. It will depend a lot on your different gems and the version of ruby/rails you have been using. There are several guides for upgrading your system to more recent versions of ruby or rails. Take a look at those and ask a new question if you have a specific question during the upgrade progress. Also don't forget to click "accept" if this answer solves your problem :)